# Google service "Oauth2" does not exist or was removed previously - Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, google-oauth, codeigniter-3, google-api-php-client

I am using google oAuth for the Codeigniter application with this composer library  `"google/apiclient": "^2.10",` for the login, and **works fine on local environment**. But it downloaded all the google services and **I don't want to upload all unnecessary libraries to the server**. So I removed all by using the following configuration file.

```
composer.json file

{
"require": {
    "google/apiclient": "^2.10",
    "google/auth": "^1.16"
},
"scripts": {
    "pre-autoload-dump": "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup"
},
"extra": {
    "google/apiclient-services": [
        "Drive",
        "YouTube"
    ]
}
```

}

But then **I received an error page on the application while authentication**

`An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error Message: Class "Google_Service_Oauth2" not found`

So I added appropriate library `"Oauth2"`  and run the `composer update' command.

```
{
"require": {
    "google/apiclient": "^2.10",
    "google/auth": "^1.16"
},
"scripts": {
    "pre-autoload-dump": "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup"
},
"extra": {
    "google/apiclient-services": [
        "Drive",
        "YouTube",
        "Oauth2"
    ]
}
```

}

The problem is  `"Oauth2"` library is not adding to the existing project using composer.

Note: I have tried to update without  `"pre-autoload-dump": "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup"` line and still it doesn't work.

Is there any way to fix this using a composer file or command. Thank you for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you community and I just found the answer.

I have to delete the **`apiclient-services`** folder completed and then need to run the composer update command.

Source:
`IMPORTANT: If you add any services back in composer.json, you will need to remove the vendor/google/apiclient-services directory explicitly for the change you made to have effect:`

[google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)

Comment: Thank you! Documentation on how to only load the Oauth2 API client was what I was looking for!